# Petri net, how to stop it after 5 times

Tags: petri-nets

I have a task to reimplement this net (library system) into a 'finite' net, which ends after 5 'readings'. I have totally no clue how to achieve this, it was our first lesson.

Is there someone that could help me?

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We do not want to just do your (home-)work for you; we want you to gain understanding. However, as it is we do not know what your underlying problem is, so we can not begin to help. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/594/the-return-of-the-homework-question) for a relevant discussion. If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]? You may also want to check out our [reference questions](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/599/).

Comment: Hint: Imagine the net as a while-loop. How do you limit a loop to five iterations?

Answer (score 1):

In order to prevent a loop from running forever you need to either

- keep track of how many times you've performed the loop using a loop counter
- change the conditions of your state machine inside the loop so that you ensure it will stop at some point.